# Error in my prepared pdo insert statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm trying to insert values using prepare statements on pdo but i'm facing this error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in
>   C:\wamp\www\chat\insert.php on line 23

```
$db = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_t` (`fk_crname_c`, `fk_username_c`, `message_c`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$sq_stat = $db->prepare($sql);
// bind column to variable for display
$sq_stat->bindColumn(1, $chatname);
$sq_stat->bindColumn(2,$username);
$sq_stat->bindColumn(3, $message);


$count=$sq_stat->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) not [`bindColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php):

```
$sq_stat -> bindParam(1, $chatname);
$sq_stat -> bindParam(2, $username);
$sq_stat -> bindParam(3, $message);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`bindColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) is for results. You want [`bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) or [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$sq_stat->bindValue(1, $chatname);
$sq_stat->bindValue(2,$username);
$sq_stat->bindValue(3, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an Insert statement try passing your values as an array to the execute function.

```
$db = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_t` (`fk_crname_c`, `fk_username_c`, `message_c`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$sq_stat = $db->prepare($sql);

$count = $sq_stat->execute(array($chatname, $username, $message));
```